# JNDI context only works once (EJB test with jUnit)

Tags: java, junit, ejb, wildfly, java-ee-7

I am trying to implement jUnit for testing an EJB. The test works fine, if I am using the JNDI context **once**. But, if I use the context a **second time** I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No EJB receiver available for handling
     [appName:Name, moduleName:NameEJB, distinctName:] combination for 
     invocation context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext
at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireEJBReceiver(
     EJBClientContext.java:774)
...
```

The *setUp()* of the test class looks as following:

```
private NameDAO nameDAO;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    try {
        final Hashtable<String, Comparable> jndiProperties = 
            new Hashtable<String, Comparable>();

        jndiProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://localhost:8080");
        jndiProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "user");
        jndiProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
        jndiProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, 
                "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
        jndiProperties.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);

        final Context context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);

        final String lookupName = "Name/NameEJB/NameBean!com.myname.ejb.interfaces.NameDAO";

        nameDAO = (NameDAO) context.lookup(lookupName);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Using the ***nameDAO*** object in the test for the first time works fine. Using it for the second time throws the exception above.

Any ideas?

I am using Java EE 7 with Wildfly 9.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

what you are trying to do is to 'hold' and reuse a reference to the EJB  service (nameDAO) for different methods. What you are missing is that eventually when you do a lookup and get a reference , you get a proxy of a bean, which is either created on the fly by the server (or you get a pooled one). When you invoke the service and you finish with it, the container returns the instance back to the pool (or destroys it ) - depending on the server and spec version. The reason that the second time it does not work, is that this specific proxy you are holding as a private variable in your test, is not pointing to a 'live' instance. You need to make a new request to the container (lookup) for another instance.

One modification you could do is actually hold the Context as a private variable and then in each test method do again the lookup to get a fresh instance (proxy).

Last but not least, I would highly suggest you have a look on Arquillian, makes this kind of testing much easier to implement and maintain. See the official guide [here](http://arquillian.org/guides/) or a sample post [here](http://javapapo.blogspot.gr/2014/06/java-ee7-and-maven-project-for-newbies.html)

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the hint on Arquillian. I still have not figured out why the proxy gets lost. I still would love to find why it crushes.

Comment: This is how Stateless Session Beans work and in general this technology spec. References of EJB(s) are pooled and re-used. This is done by the container automatically. When your first method completes, the proxy which points ton NameDAORef1 is no longer valid, since the container has returned this reference back to the pool. You need to get a new one.

Answer (score 0):

This is not, how you unit test an EJB. You almost never have the need to do JNDI lookups anymore.

While @javapapo's reference to Arquillian is good when in need of container mechanisms like dependency injection, this kind of test is an integration test of several components. When writing a unit test, you want to only test the unit and with EJB 3.x you can do that, since an EJB is a POJO and thus not different from any other plain old java class you unit test. So the only thing you need on top of that is a mocking framework like [Mockito](http://mockito.org/) to mock away the references to other beans which in a real container would be filled by DI.